# cant find a way to show inline content from the same page using lightbox2

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming, lightbox2

i am using the lightbox2 module in my drupal site.
i would like to be able to trigger the lightbox on content that lies withing the same page.
something like this:

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="#">Show content in light box</a>
<div id="content_to_show">the content i want to show in my light box</div>
```

cant figure out a way to do that.
any help ?

Comment: well after searching around, i have came to the conclusion that lightbox is not the proper plug in to use.
instead i am using the colorbox plugin at http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ which has this capability integrated

Answer (score 2):

well after searching around, i have came to the conclusion that lightbox is not the proper plug in to use.
instead i am using the colorbox plugin at http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ which has this capability integrated, and simple to use.

Comment: This is the same course of action I'm now pursuing.  The only other thing that would make it even better would be a way to show node body content via a separate call.